# The if statement runs even though I input the statement to run elif

Tags: python

I'm making a auto-pick program where it will pick a specific tv show or movie depending on whether you want to watch a movie or a tv show. The first if statement picks a movie and the elif statement picks a tv show. Even though I input the statement to run elif, it will always run if, and never run elif.

```py
>answer=input('Welcome to Showpicker. First off, would you like to watch a movie or a TV show? '  )
    if answer := 'Movie''movie':
         import time
         import random
         print('Great choice!')
         time.sleep(1)
         print('I will now pick a movie for you to watch!')  
         movie = ['The Hunt','Atonement','Da Vinci Code','The Menu','Dead Poets Society','Harry Potter      `Series','The Shining','Exorcist','1917','Maurice','Call Me by Your Name','The Father','Fantastic Beasts Series','James Bond Series','Dune','Dune 2','Indiana Jones Series','Drive','Blade Runner    Series','John Wick Series','Mission Impossible series','Drive','The Name of the Rose']
         time.sleep(3)
         print(random.choice(movie))
         time.sleep(3)
         print("Enjoy!Don't forget your popcorn.")
         exit()
    elif answer:='TV show''TVshow''tv show''tvshow':
        import time
        import random
        print('Great choice!')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('I will now pick a TV show for you to watch!')
        TV = ['Hannibal','Peaky Blinders','House MD','Stranger Things','Breaking Bad','The Mentalist']
        time.sleep(3)
        print(random.choice(TV))
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Enjoy!Don't forget your popcorn.")
        exit()
```

As a result, it will always show the movie option even though whether I input Tv show or movie.

Comment: `answer := 'Movie''movie'` is an assignment, not a test, which you'd have seen if you'd done some basic debugging with `print`! You want `if answer in ('Movie', 'movie'):`

Comment: Now I get the problem, and my program works. Thank you so much for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> if answer := 'Movie''movie':
> ```

The `:=` operator *(since Python 3.8)* assigns `'Movie''movie'` (which is equivalent to `'Moviemovie'` to `answer`. Because `'Moviemovie'` is always true, this assignment expression is always true and this always runs.

You likely meant to test if `answer` is equal to either `'Movie'` or `'movie'`. E.g.

```
if answer == 'Movie' or answer == 'movie':
```

Or:

```
if answer in ('Movie', 'movie'):
```

Or even more flexible with regards to spelling:

```
if answer.lower() == 'movie':
```

Comment: This is very easy to understand, and it fixed my problem! Thank you so much, itwas very helpful.